# client.event does not add prefix to json file on_guild_add (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to create an event when bot gets added in json bot adds a prefix:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '//'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

but i dont understand why this error appears:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/projects/bots/textjson.py", line 14, in <module>
    @client.event
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

is there something wrong with my code or???

*also here's the import script*

```py
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error's saying that it couldn't find a variable called `client`. What did you name the following?

```py
... = commands.Bot(command_prefix=...
```

Usually people name this `client` or `bot`, so just double check you're referencing the name that you think you are.

---

Another reason this might appear is if you've put the event *above* the line where you defined the `client` variable:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(.....

client = commands.Bot(.....
```

Should be re-ordered like so:

```py
client = commands.Bot(.....

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(.....
```